# 'Javapackege' object in not callable : pyspark error

Tags: pyspark

This is my simple python script where I want to use `self.__sql_context` for some sql operation.

`conf = SparkConf().setMaster('local[*]')
sc = SparkContext.getOrCreate(conf)
self.__sql_context = SQLContext.getOrCreate(sc)`

The line `sc = SparkContext.getOrCreate(conf)` is throwing exception like `'Javapackage' object is not callable`(I used try...except here, so i came to know it's on this line).

I doubt there is some problem with java or spark configuration. Can anybody please help what the reason might be ? Thanks in advance !

I'M USING A VM OF CLOUDERA, CENTOS 6.7